# Android Studio problem: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

I recive this error (E/ERRO: Network error IOException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 1433) from /:: (port 40722): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)) after I try to run useing Android Studio an app on my phone. After I start tu run the code, my phone first have lag, and after one minute or something like this, in Android Studio I see the error.

I tried to change the ip, I set my ip, localhost, and everything I found but with another IP I recive this error  connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out), only with 127.0.0.1 the error is changeing.
I am also connected on the same wifi with my phone.
Phpmyadmin work just fine, but I don't know what else I should do...

Here is my connection class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class ConnectionClass {
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String IP, DB, DBuserName, DBPassword;





    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        IP = "127.0.0.1";
        DB = "users_details";
        DBuserName = "root";
        DBPassword = "revolution";
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        java.sql.Connection connection = null;

        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs);

            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + IP +";databaseName=" + DB + ";password=" + DBPassword + ";";


            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your setup? Connecting to localhost:1443 attempts to connect from the phone to the phone. Is anything running there on port 1443?

Comment: My XAMPP setup? For MySQL my.ini is here https://codeshare.io/ad90ZZ and config.inc.php is here https://codeshare.io/a3JnWL . And no, I don't have anything on that port running